# Adding a number suffix when creating folder in C#

Tags: c#, directory, counter

I'm trying to handle if the folder i want to create is already exist .. to add a number to folder name .. like windows explorer .. e.g(New Folder , New Folder 1 , New Folder 2 ..)
how can i do it recursively
i know this code is wrong.
how can i fix or maybe change the code below to solve the problem ?

```
    int i = 0;
    private void NewFolder(string path)
    {
        string name = "\\New Folder";
        if (Directory.Exists(path + name))
        {
            i++;
            NewFolder(path + name +" "+ i);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + name);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this, you don't need recursion, but instead should look to an iterative solution:

```cs
private void NewFolder(string path) {
    string name = @"\New Folder";
    string current = name;
    int i = 1;
    while (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path, current))) {
        i++;
        current = String.Format("{0}{1}", name, i);
    }
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, current));
}
```

Comment: thanks alot :) .. mm i have a lil question .. i made a file explorer using treeview .. now i want to do it using listview .. how to get ParentNode.. in listview.. i mean the current folder.. is there an option in listviewitem or i have to save the current path in a string ?

Comment: The `ListViewItem` object has a `Tag` property where you can store arbitrary data. You could put the path here.

Comment: cool .. for some reason which i don't know why.. when i give the path @"d:" .. it created on disk c: .. whyy ??

Comment: @MurHafSoz it's a really annoying legacy issue with Windows.  If you don't specify up to at least the backslash it will give you behavior you don't expect.  So `d:\` is different than `d:`

Comment: sorry for my bad english ...  i didn't get your point, how should i pass the path ?

Comment: @MurHafSoz no problem. You need to pass at least c:\ instead of just c:

Comment: actually when i console.writeline(Path.Combine(path, current))
it shows me \new folder .. only .. so it might be taking the current directory which is c: .. something is wrong with PATH.COMBINE .. check it out

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7143/discussion-between-mur-haf-soz-and-jaredpar)

Comment: This was a helpful post. I just want to note that the while statement is missing a third `)`. Should look like this: `while (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(path, current))) {`

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void NewFolder(string path) 
    {
        string name = @"\New Folder";
        string current = name;
        int i = 0;
        while (Directory.Exists(path + current))
        {
            i++;
            current = String.Format("{0} {1}", name, i);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path + current);
    }
```

credit for @JaredPar

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to do it is:

```
        public static void ebfFolderCreate(Object s1)
        {
          DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(s1.ToString());
          if (di.Parent != null && !di.Exists)
          {
              ebfFolderCreate(di.Parent.FullName);
          }

          if (!di.Exists)
          {
              di.Create();
              di.Refresh();
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this DirectoryInfo extender:

```
public static class DirectoryInfoExtender
{
    public static void CreateDirectory(this DirectoryInfo instance)
    {
        if (instance.Parent != null)
        {
            CreateDirectory(instance.Parent);
        }
        if (!instance.Exists)
        {
            instance.Create();
        }
    }
}
```